# adding two int array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have to add two int[] array in which a mian int[] array is intially vacant. I want to add the elements of another array in the main array . In the Main array, there would be more addtion that would be added in the last postion of the main array.

I have an array as  -

```
var planetNotInRange = new int[7] ;

if(planetSign.Contains(tempFrind))
{
    var result = planetSign.Select((b, k) => b.Equals(tempFrind) ? k : -1)
                           .Where(k => k != -1).ToArray();

    // Here I want to add this result Array in to the planetNotInRange array, 
    // when ever there is some value in the result array.
}
```

this is in loop will give a number of array of integers. Now I want to concat in PLanetInRange Array one after other.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: I have an array as  -

var planetNotInRange = new int[7] ;

var result = planetSign.Select((b, k) => b.Equals(tempFrind) ? k : -1).Where(k => k != -1).ToArray();
this is in loop will give a number of array of integers.
Now I want to concat in PLanetInRange Array one after other.

Comment: Don't add it as a comment - edit full details into your question.

Comment: Do you mean add or merge two arrays?

Comment: Indeed - it's *still* not clear what the result should be. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Until your question is clear, it's wasting everyone's time - including your own. Note that you can't increase the size of an array - you can either replace the elements, or you can create a new array.

Comment: yes, each time when ever result will have some array of integers it should be added to the PlanetInRange ayyarys.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you shouldn't have an array to start with, if you want to add elements to it. Once an array has been created, its size is fixed.

Use a `List<int>` instead, and you can use

```
list.AddRange(array);
```

I'd usually advise using lists (and other collection types) over arrays anyway. Arrays *are* useful, obviously, but they're somewhat more primitive and low-level than other collections.